# I created a button component with a loader integrated in VueJs. I passed my loader as props but I can't get it to work with a method in a vueJs page,

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

here is my component

```
 <button
class="BtnLoader btn btn-primary-contained btn-iconed btn-mobile btn-important"
@click="onClick"
:aria-label="label"
:title="title">
<i v-if="loader" class="spinner  icon-spinner3"></i>
<span v-if="loader" class="followingText">{{ textBtnLoader }}</span>
<span v-else class="followingText">{{ textBtn }}</span>
<i class="icon icon-arrow-right"></i>
```

it works if i tell it true or false in the component but it's not the behavior i expect how to pass it to my method?

I would like to pass this to my method

```
<BtnLoader
      label="test"
      title="test BTN"
      textBtn="TEST BTN"
      textBtnLoader="Loading"
      :onClick="test"
      :loader="false"
    />

  test() {
  this.loader = !false;
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert('test btn');
  }, 2000);
  this.loader = !true;
},
```

Comment: Is there any errors?

Comment: no I am not an error only it only works if I put true or false in my button and is not taken into account by the method

Comment: It doesn't make sense to write `!false`, why don't just `true` instead? same thing with `!true`. I'm assuming that you want to change the value of `this.loader` to whatever is opposite

Comment: it is a loader on the button that appears and disappears once the download is completed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
test () {
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert('test btn');
  }, 2000);
  this.loader = !this.loader;
},
```

Make sure to remove the `v-bind` on `loader`, so just `loader="false"` instead of `:loader="false"`. Vue will treat `true` as primitives without v-bind, otherwise as variables or methods

Comment: I can tell that you also pass the `test()` as a prop to this component, so make sure you have `test()` in the parent component

Comment: if I delete the v-bin the loader is still active (true) while in the button props it is by default a false

Comment: I don't understand I have to pass test () to my button how?

Comment: @lidianmanoha. where does the function `test()` sit currently? I assumed in the `BtnLoader` component?

Comment: As I can tell, it starts from here `@click="onClick"`, when the `click` event happens, it triggers the function `onClick`. The function `onClick` is passed down from the parent component as a prop `:onClick="test"`, and the value you pass to it is `test` which should be a function in your parent component.

Comment: to be clearer the goal is to create a component button with a reusable loader knowing that the method is on another page where the component is imported

Comment: So do you want to update the boolean `loader` from another page accordingly ?

Comment: yes I want to trigger the Boolean in the method when I click on it

Comment: Why don't you just have the `loader` locally in your `BtnLoader` component, then the button `click` event toggles it between `true` and `false` ? Or is there any dependencies of this boolean in another page?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand I'm new to vuejs but I can have several buttons in one page with different method and in another page with other method and I want the loader to trigger only on the click button if you have  an example or a procedure thank you